# Why do PhD students do research for other people’s research ideas?

Tags: phd

I’m a research assistant with an idea for a new study.  I’ve started my literature review, however a couple of people have said to me there are plenty of PhD students who would be keen to help with the research.  Why would a PhD student want to do research on a topic that’s not potentially of any interest to them?

Comment: *baffled at the close votes* I could understand considering this "primarily opinion-based", but how can you possibly say "unclear what you're asking"? The question is clear in the final sentence.

Answer (score 14):

If they want to help, it implies that they *are* interested. Multiple people can work on research projects and get a benefit from them.

I've helped on numerous projects and ended up getting a name on the resulting research paper. I wasn't able to use that research in my PhD thesis, but any job applications look a lot stronger as I have experience in a good variety of projects.

Comment: Thanks Richard, it makes so much more sense now 

Answer (score 6):

As Richard said, there are plenty of reasons to offer help and getting publication is one of the reasons. It sounds likely that your topic is in an area that will likely to be published and hence the interest level would be high and publications will help PhD students and their careers.

Another reason is to learn new techniques and improve their skillset. Maybe your lit review covers methodologies that students want to learn and engage with. Doing the project with you will help them diversify their research skills.

Other reasons may be more directly due to you. You may be likeable or engaging. People may want to spend more time and you may have an uplifting effect on people as well. I am sure you can think of many interpersonal reasons as well.

Comment: Or, they might just find the topic interesting!

Answer (score 4):

They are PhD students, i.e. they are just starting out and are not able to come up with exciting new ideas themselves. They might not even have had serious research experience. Sure, it's possible to cite some fancy topic ("I want to solve the Riemann hypothesis!") but knowing whether it's feasible to attack that problem in the time available is something else entirely.

If the PhD student attempts the topic and finds it's not interesting to them, then chances are they'll stop working on it. After they've already worked on a few topics (i.e. a few years into their PhD program) that's when they will get more selective about what to work on.

Answer (score 1):

My specialization (computer vision) is such that *I can easily work in many application domains* (e.g. satellite and multispectral imaging, medical imaging, agri-robotics). I can develop my research line and interests equally well with *many* different sources of data, as long as my work is supported. Getting familiar with new domain-specific challenges is a very gentle way to expand my expertise.

What I want to say, in addition to all the great reasons listed in the other answers (chance for publication, establishing collaborative connections, new skills) is that - **a PhD student's fit or interest in the topic might not be as obvious at first glance**, but knowledge transfer between domains can be a strong motivator as well.

This might be even more pronounced in an informal lab setting where the names of interested students might have been just mentioned in passing and you looked up their profiles yourself (*e.g. why would somebody looking at remote images of urban environments suddenly want to work in robotic farming?*). Which is why letting the students explain their interests (by having a chat) is a good way to see where their motivation comes from (*e.g. because the underlying problem is semantic scene segmentation both for remote and agricultural images, and that person is interested in semantic segmentation*).